# Stencil and Sass file

Tags: stenciljs

I am trying to port a React component to [Stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29).

The component *.scss* file has an *@import* for another *A.scss* file. That *A.scss* file *@import* the *bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheet/bootstrap/_variables* and *@import* another *B.scss* file.

Can Stencil handle that or do I need to merge everything in one file?

Comment: Should this be tagged with JavaScript (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 4):

You can import other Sass files; you don't need to merge everything to one single file.

You can keep using Sass as you are using it with React. Just keep in mind that to be able to use Sass with Stencil, you have to install the Sass plugin and add the plugin to the `plugins` array in your *stencil.config.js* file.

For more information, check the [Sass documentation](https://stenciljs.com/docs/sass) on the Stencil website.

Answer (score 2):

In your *stencil.config.ts* (or *stencil.config.js*) file:

```javascript
export const config: Config = {
  plugins: [
    sass({
      includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/styles')]
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: This will work, but will also bloat all web-components in your project with this 'global' css.

Comment: We might need a device in the web-component architecture to allow specific CSS classes through the shadowDOM to facilitate parent frameworks. But that would be a hassle (...) and against the main principle of web-components: "encapsulated styling and custom behavior".
Or a smart stencil feature to compile specific css classes (that we actually use) into a component..!
I will keep struggling for an optimal solution within the current specifications :-/

Comment: This looks like the right answer but I get red `Cannot find name 'path'.ts(2304)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can handle Sass files and their imports.

Install package *stencil/sass*:

`npm i @stencil/sass -D`

In your *stencil.config.ts* file:

```typescript
import { Config } from "@stencil/core";
import { sass } from "@stencil/sass";

export const config: Config = {
  // ... You configuration
  plugins: [
    sass({
      includePaths: ["./node_modules/"],
    }),
  ],

};
```

In the above example, we're telling the Stencil compiler to compile Sass files. The `includePaths` array tells the compiler the directories/files it should look into for the Sass files.

In order to use `@import` from a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) package, all you need is:

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheet/bootstrap/_variables";
```

Note: The *~* operator here is necessary when not importing using relative paths(*./style.scss*, *../../style.scss*, etc.)

If you are importing the `b.scss` file using relative paths (*./b.scss*, *../b.scss*, etc.), you won't need to add anything else to Sass plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried multiple imports, but I can't see why this wouldn't work.

To get Stencil working with *.scss*, you should install this plugin, as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stencil/sass).

```
npm install @stencil/sass --save-dev
```

Then add this property to `config` in file *stencil.config.ts*.

```
plugins: [
    sass()
  ]
```